# Redis Channel configuration for Publish subscribe

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

How long will messages published to a Redis channel stay there ? Also, is there is a way to configure the max. lifetime of a message per channel ? Is there a way to control the channel size or does the channel continues to store messages as long as the Redis server has free memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis pub/sub doesn't persist published messages. What you are looking for seems more like a message queue which can be implemented using a combination of pub/sub and lists. For more information see pattern sections in [RPOPLPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) command.